# Reference requested for homotopy theory theorem

Tags: reference-request, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory, higher-homotopy-groups

I came across this post:
[Homotopy groups of compact topological manifold](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/147731/homotopy-groups-of-compact-topological-manifold)
which states exactly the result I need for a theorem I'm working on.  However, I would need a reference, since the audience need not be very well-versed in homotopy theory.

Could someone suggest where I can find the result:

> **Theorem:** Every closed, connected smooth $d$-manifold $M$ has a continuous and not nullhomotopic map $f: S^{d'} \rightarrow M$ for some sphere $S^{d'}$ with $1 \leq d' \leq \dim(M)$.

In other words, if $M$ is a closed and connected smooth manifold then there is a non-trivial $\pi_{d'}(M)$ for some $d'\leq \dim(M)$.

Comment: What is the audience? Would it suffice to say the manifold is orientable mod $2$ so the cohomology is nontrivial and therefore the manifold is not contractible?

Comment: It may surprising (I am also surprised at-times) but the audience are probabilists...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a reference but a short proof:

if not, then with $d'=1$ we see that $M$ would have to be simply-connected.

In particular, if its homology groups all vanish, then $M$ is contractible. But the homology groups in dimension $> \dim(M)$ always vanish, and the hypothesis implies (by Hurewicz) that the homology groups in dimension $\leq \dim(M)$ vanish too.

This implies that $M$ is contractible, which is impossible by Poincaré duality (either mod $2$, or integrally because $M$ is simply-connected)

More simply put: $M$ is mod $2$-orientable, so it must have nontrivial mod $2$-cohomology, this must be in dimension $\leq \dim(M)$, but the hypothesis implies it doesn't, by the Hurewciz theorem.

Comment: I think you don't need to go all the way to getting a contradiction using contractibility. Just note that if $M$ is simply connected then by the Hurewicz theorem the lowest degree in which its homotopy is nonzero is also the lowest degree in which its homology is nonzero, and by Poincare duality $H_{\dim M}(M, \mathbb{Z})$ is nonzero so homology is first nonzero in some degree $\le \dim M$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan : you're right ! although to some extent that's what I said in my last paragraph